# Drupal Embedded views not working correctly

Tags: drupal, view, updates

I recently took over a site from someone else at a new company.  Having never used Drupal before, updating things has been a bit cumbersome.  There were some outstanding security updates that I applied(but I haven't updated the core yet).  Anyway, after doing this, the calls to views_embeded_view have not been working.  For example:

print views_embed_view('news_block');

Will break the links(by using the title, rather than alias for the link), or it will link correctly, but not follow the paging rules I have set(show 1 page, 6 items per page) instead it shows 10 items and has links for other pages.

I am not sure if the update has anything to do with it, but it seems likely.  Would updating the core resolve this issue potentially?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of views_embed_view is view name, the second one is display id. If display_id is not provided, 'default' is used. Make sure that you are displaying the correct display. (i.e. *default* can be configured differently than some other display which you actually wish to see)